# Firebase Cloud Messaging PHP

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send a message to a specific person using Google Firebase Cloud with PHP. The token of the person who receives the message is stored in the DB.
Here is my code:

```
define('SERVER_API_KEY','MYSERVERAPIKEY');
define('FRIEND_TOKEN','FRIEND_TOKEN')

$message = array(
    'title'=>'Bet invitation',
    'body' =>'Notification from ...',
);
$url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send'; 
$fields = array(
    'registration_ids' => FRIEND_TOKEN,
    'data' => $message
);
$headers = array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: key='.SERVER_API_KEY
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ($result === FALSE) {
    die('FCM Send Error: ' . curl_error($ch));
}
echo "Result: $result";
echo "Curl: ". curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

The problem is that the specified user doesn't get a message. And when I test it through the Firebase console, it works ... However, the error message is strangely not shown to me either :(

Comment: Please go read [ask]. _“Does not work”_ is not a useful problem description.

Comment: Any errors, what was it ?

Comment: Okay, the problem is that the specified user doesn't get a message and when I test it through the Firebase console, it works

Comment: print_r($result); @MalteLange

Comment: `{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
` @ashokan

Comment: I think you are using an invalid token, please verify it and the below posted code is worked for me. @MalteLange

Comment: Also try to pass headers like this,

$headers = array(
       'Content-Type: application/json',
       'Authorization: key =' MYSERVERAPIKEY
   ); @MalteLange

Comment: My server API key is correct and the "'to' => $device_id" this is the key to which the message is sent. If I put the key in the firebase it strangely works ... I tried your approach but it still doesn't work, Error code: Unauthorized, ERROR 401 @ashokan

Comment: Try header like this , 

 $headers = array(
          'Content-Type: application/json',
          'Authorization: key =' MYSERVERAPIKEY ); @MalteLange

Comment: `registration_ids` is an array of strings, in your case you should use `[FRIEND_TOKEN]` or `array(FRIEND_TOKEN)`. Or use `to` instead of `registration_ids`. See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code, hope it will help.

```
$message=[
    'title'=>'Bet invitation',
    'body' =>'Notification from ...',
];

$send = $this->GoogleCloudMessaging($friend_token,$message);
echo $send;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have now found the problem myself. I added `"gcm_sender_id": "YOUR_FIREBASE_PROJECT_SENDER_ID"` to the manifest.json file and rewritten the script, here is the solution:

```
define('SERVER_API_KEY', 'MYSERVERAPIKEY');

$data = array(
   "to" => "$RECIVER_TOKEN",
   "notification" => array(
       "title" => "Test-Title",
       "body" => "Test-Message",
       "icon" => "https://url/images/iamge.png",
       "click_action" => "https://url")
    );

$headers = array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: key=' . SERVER_API_KEY
);
$url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ($result === FALSE) {
   die('FCM Send Error: ' . curl_error($ch));
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Greetings to: 
   ashokan, David Angulo and https://santhoshveer.com/web-push-notification/